# Angular HttpClient post not working

Tags: angular, rest, http, oauth-2.0

I'm changing my code to change my http api from '@angular/http' to '@angular/common/http'.  Most of my requests are working fine, but the authentication that brings me the refresh token isn't working, no matter how hard I try....  Please, seem my code bellow:

```
    const headerHttp = new HttpHeaders();
    headerHttp.set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    headerHttp.set('Authorization', 'Basic YW5ndWxhcjphbmd1bGFy');

    this.clientHttp.post(this.oauthTokenUrl,
      { username: user, password: pwd , grant_type: 'password' },
      {  headers: headerHttp, withCredentials: true })
        .subscribe(
      res => {
         console.log(res);
      },
      err => {
         console.log('Error occured');
      }
    );
```

But the parameters ( username, password and grant_type ) aren't being reaching the server and an input screen is popping.

[image]

This is my the result of my request that works, with '@angular/http':

IMAGE 1
[image]

This is the result of my request that doesn't work, which code I put above.

IMAGE 2
[image]

**EDIT** **1** - The authentication input screen isn´t popping up anymore with the code bellow.

```
const _params = new HttpParams()
.set('grant_type', 'password')
.set('username', usuario)
.set('password', senha );

const _headers = new HttpHeaders()
  .set('Authorization', 'Basic YW5ndWxhcjphbmd1bGFy')
  .set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

const httpOptions = {
  headers: _headers,
  params: _params,
  withCredentials: true
};

this.clientHttp.post<String>(this.oauthTokenUrl, httpOptions).subscribe(
res => {
  console.log(res);
},
err => {
  console.log('Error occurred', err);
});
```

**THIS** is what my code used to be, and work Ok.

```
    const headers = new Headers();

    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic YW5ndWxhcjphbmd1bGFy');

    const body = `username=${usuario}&password=${senha}&grant_type=password`;

    return this.http.post(this.oauthTokenUrl, body,
        { headers, withCredentials: true })
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => {
        this.armazenarToken(response.json().access_token);
      })
      .catch(response => {
        if (response.status === 400) {
          const responseJson = response.json();

          if (responseJson.error === 'invalid_grant') {
            return Promise.reject('Usuário ou senha inválida!');
          }
        }

        return Promise.reject(response);
      });
  }
```

But now the HttpClient creates a "Request Payload" instead of a "Form Data".  Why? The servlet cannot read "Request Payload" the same way he used to read "Form Data", so it doesn't do the authentication properly.

***EDIT 2 - The Solution***

After a ton of tries, what make it work was a new FormData() that I put following @mtpultz suggestion.

```
const params = new HttpParams()
.set('grant_type', 'password')
.set('username', user)
.set('password', pwd );

const headers = new HttpHeaders()
  .set('Authorization', 'Basic xpto')
  .set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

const httpOptions = {
  headers: headers,
  params: params,
  withCredentials: true
};

//The line works ( Requisition with Form Data, like IMAGE 1 above )
this.httpClient.post<Response>(this.oauthTokenUrl,  new FormData(), httpOptions )

//The line, without new FormData(), doesn't work.  ( Requisition with Request Payload, like IMAGE 2 above )
this.httpClient.post<Response>(this.oauthTokenUrl,  httpOptions )
```

Comment: You'll need to provide a bit more of the surrounding code I think in order to figure this out since what you've done appears to be correct.

Comment: @mtpultz, I tried to remove all the surroundings of the code, even the HttpInterceptor, without changing the outcome.  But I added more information and the problem seems to be more clear to me.  Unfortunatelly, not the solution... :-(  Tks!

Comment: Yah your original code wouldn't work for sure since `HttpClient` requests and responses are immutable so `headers.append(...)` actually returns a copy that you would have needed to store by doing `headers = headers.append(...)`, but instead you weren't storing it, and `headers` would need to be `let` not `const` if you were doing it that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Putting your code into a [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-http-client-test?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) this seems to send `Form Data` and not as `Request Payload` when you view it in the console.  The reason it sends properly I believe is based on native forms submitting form field name/values pairs as a query-string, which adding them as params mimics.

```
  public test() {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Authorization': 'Basic YW5ndWxhcjphbmd1bGFy'
    });
    const params = new HttpParams()
      .set('username', 'test@example.com')
      .set('password', 'secret')
      .set('grant_type', 'password');
    const options = {
      headers,
      params,
      withCredentials: true
    };
    this.httpClient.post('https://reqres.in/api/example', null, options)
      .subscribe(response => console.log(response));
  }
```

Also, I'd suggest using `Observables` and not converting your responses to `Promises`.  If you're not comfortable with `Observables` yet it won't take long to learn some basics just to handle HTTP requests.

Comment: this last version, without the "new FormData()", didn't work.  Thankfully your first solution still does.  :-)   The code is the same above plus "withCredentials: true".   I edited again adding "new FormData()" as the solution, even if it's not totally clear to me the reasons behind this behavior.

Comment: I don't think passing `new FormData()` makes it work properly.  You should be able to pass `null` and get the same result.  I think this works since native forms on submit would add form field name/value pairs as a query-string to a request.  So by adding them as params produces the same query-string result that mimics a native form submission.

Comment: can you tell if this is a similar issue to what i am having here? https://github.com/elfelround/pangeanic/blob/b9a28259bf10a94d497b1cbaca93158db3c9d065/frontend/src/app/creationform/creationform.component.ts

Comment: You're only providing the code, but don't explain the issue.  I would say no since you're not using HttpParams.  Are you getting an error?